# I have two edges that intersect, how do I get a vertex at the intersection point?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

[image: The Problem area.]

I tried adding this edge with the knife tool to no avail, it won't add in the desired vertices. Is there any other way to add these vertices and have them connected to both edges like the ones above?

**[blend file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105695273/%25%20Block.blend)**

Comment: The knife tool works for me.. Is it possible you could upload your .blend? Also try selecting the end vertices and pressing `J`.

Comment: `J` didn't work, it had the same affects as `F` [Here is the .blend file.] (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105695273/%25%20Block.blend)

Comment: That's very odd. J crashes blender for me, I've reported this as a bug here: https://developer.blender.org/T42513

Comment: Crash here too...

Comment: This is fixed by https://developer.blender.org/rBb7174c9320c5e3446d8237059841d982279e32e9

Comment: @ideasman42 That'll teach me to test latest master before reporting.. BTW, IMO the question shouldn't be closed. The crashing was not part of the question, that was just a side effect discovered while attempting an answer. It seems the real problem is that the vertical edges in the OP's file are not connected to the face. Jack Brand: Probably best to delete the edges and then cut with J or knife, or delete the face and the edges and use grid fill.

Comment: @gandalf3, your right, too hasty response on my part.

Comment: knife tool works for me fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently knife would be good to use. For this particular case, there are some tricks to do it even faster:

**Trick 1:**

1. Select all intersected edges, then <kbd>P</kbd> > **Selection**;
2. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> to quickly search for **Knife Project** tool.
3. Switch to **Object Mode**, delete the separated object (edges).

[image]

---

**Trick 2:**

1. Select the n-gon face while using *Face Select* mode, then switch to *Vertex Select* mode to quickly select related elements (or simply press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all elements in this case);
2. Hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to search for **Split by Edge** tool;
3. Select the two vertices on that horizontal edge, then press <kbd>J</kbd>.

[image]

---

**P.S.:**

There are some addons that are aimed to split intersecting edges, such as zeffii's [X ALL](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/5539910), nixy's [Boolean 2D Union](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?338703-Addon-Boolean-2D-Union), even the powerful [Sverchok](http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverchok_ru.html) can handle some situations. they all got pros and cons, however. IMHO, We really need an internal tool to perfectly handle it (something like an enhanced version of the current **Split by Edge** tool).

Comment: Trick 2 works like a charm. X All is also Very very nice. I recommend it in everyones default addons. Thanks a lot Leon, dont know what I would have done without you.

Comment: You are welcome. all great tools mentioned above are @ideasman42 (Campbell) 's babies. Let's thank him. :)