# How can an empty be added at intersection of edges using Python?

Tags: python

I have 2 *Edges* intersecting at 90 degree. How can I add an *Empty* aligned to them. I suppose this can be done using `mathutils`. I need the **matrix** and not just the `Translation` component which is not aligned.

Thanks, this will be very useful!

[image: Empty]

Comment: Do the answers to question [18565](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18565/) provide any help? Except for the Python aspect, this appears to be identical to that question.

Comment: No, the answers to question 18565 don't help but the answer below does work like a charm! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting the location is indeed trivial, even more with [`mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_line()`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_line).

Getting rotation here is not so hard either. Let's call your two edges e1 and e2 (note that this is theoretical code, assuming you have your `vertices` array and `empty` object already at hand):

```
# We get 'average' intersection point - in case the two edges do not actually exactly intersect.
inter = mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_line(vertices[e1.v1].co, vertices[e1.v2].co, vertices[e2.v1].co, vertices[e2.v2].co)
vi = (inter[0] + inter[1]) / 2

# Then, we get our first axis.
ax = (vertices[e1.v1].co - vi).normalized()

# We get our third axis by cross product of first axis and second edge.
az = (ax.cross(vertices[e2.v1].co - vi)).normalized()

# Then second axis is crossproduct of the first and third ones.
# Note that if you know for sure your two edges are orthogonal,
# You can skip that and rather create ay exactly as we did with ax.
ay = (az.cross(ax)).normalized()

# Those three axes allow us to create a rotation matrix directly.
# However, we need to put them as columns, not rows. Since matrix
# creation in Blender uses rows, we'll have to transpose it.
mrot = mathutils.Matrix((ax, ay, az))
mrot.transpose()

# And now, we just have to make this a 4d matrix and add translation component.
mat = mrot.to_4x4()
mat.translation = vi

# And set this a base matrix of our empty:
empty.matrix_basis = mat
```